# Meteor class being fired multiple times from JQuery.click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I have a generic template that I use multiple times.

```
{{#each item}}
   {{> genericTemplate}}
{{/each}}
```

Inside of this template I have a button that when it is clicked fires a hidden file input in the generic template.

```
 $(".upload").click();
```

Unfortunately for each template  the ".upload" class gets fired. So if I had four `items`, it would give me 4 file inputs. I can't give the buttons a unique `id=""` because then I would have to explicitly define each event for each id, negating the entire reason for creating the generic template in the first place. What is the proper way to achieve something like this?

EDIT:

My template events look like this:

```
Template.generic.events({
   'click .fileUpload' : function () {
     $(".upload").click(); // sets off the 4 templates .upload class
   },
  'change .upload' : function (e) {
    console.log('upload')
   }
})
```

HTML:

```
<template name="generic">
   <!--Hidden Inputs that get fired on click events -->
   <div class="hiddenFile">
      <input type="file" class="upload"/>
   </div>

  <button class="btn btn-success fileUpload">UPLOAD FILE </button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this trick :

```
Template.generic.events({
  'click .fileUpload' : function (event,template) {
    // fires only the template instance .upload
    template.$(".upload").click();
  },
  'change .upload' : function (e) {
    console.log('upload')
  }
});
```

Comment: Please see edits. I understand defining events. Let me know if I am not being clear on the issue.

Comment: Awesome it worked. Is it bad practice to do it this way?

Comment: File input in HTML5 as we are speaking is a bit of a mess because it is not easily stylable with CSS, so usually you end up hiding it and trigger it using various tricks. So it's not a bad practice by itself, more like a bandage. If you want nice file uploads that are both developer and user friendly, consider using uploadcare, filepicker or any third party file upload service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Template.instance`](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_instance) to fire the event in only the appropriate instance:

```
'click .fileUpload' : function () {
  var template = Template.instance();
  template.$(".upload").click(); // should only set off this specific upload input.
}
```

That said, is there really no way you can achieve the same effect without manufacturing an event in the DOM?  It's up to you, but can't you just run the code that's going to replace `console.log('upload')` directly?

Comment: That template instance was what I was missing. Is this bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe smth like this?

```
Template.generic.events({
    'click .fileUpload' : function (event, target) {
       e.currentTarget.parent().find(".upload").click(); // sets off the 4 templates .upload class
    },
    'change .upload' : function (e) {
        console.log('upload')
    }
})
```